# How can Key Compromise Impersonation be mitigated?

Tags: encryption, tls

[This paper](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/woot15/woot15-paper-hlauschek.pdf) describes a successful attack on TLS called Key Compromise Impersonation.  It states that the attack can be mitigated thus:

1. Disable non-ephemeral (EC)DH handshakes
2. Set appropriate X509 Key Usage extension for ECDSA and DSS certificates
3. Disable specifically the `KeyAgreement` flag

How can I identify which ciphers to disable for (1), and how do I make the changes to my certificates in (2) and (3)?  If necessary, please assume I'm using OpenSSL and Apache.

Comment: What version of OpenSSL and Apache are you using?

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1e and Apache 2.2.22 (both from Debian oldstable packages).

Answer (score 2):

1) Look at the seventh page of the document. There is a list of them:

```
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256  
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256  
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA  
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA  
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA  
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA  
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA  
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA  
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA  
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384  
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Also, looking at your versions, you should disable ephermal DH handshakes (and allow only ephermal ECDH), because you cannot supply in this version your own DH prime, so you will use the common insecure one.

2, 3) You will have to contact your certification authority. You cannot modify the certificate.